# How does the page fault handler know where to get the 4K bytes?

Tags: linux, page-tables, pagefile

I mean, which file and what's the offset into the file?

The page fault handler need to copy 4K bytes from there into the physical RAM.

----------------------EDIT----------------------------

I found out that `vm_file` in `vm_area_struct` was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `vm_file` in `vm_area_struct` was just what I was looking for. – xiaokaoy